# Trying to identify a specific animated show from my childhood

Tags: story-identification, tv, powers, animation, animated-series

I'm 25 years old, and I have a vague memory of an animated kids show where the characters used data chips or cards to give themselves different abilities. I think I remember the Main character using a laser blade and a laser cannon. They might have used rarer cards/chips that gave them more powerful attacks. I know it sounds a bit like Megaman but I've not seen anything from Megaman that lines up with what I remember. Please help me because this has been bothering me for years!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and can you give us a sense of what any of the characters looked like? Also, was the show animated in 2D (hand-drawn) or 3D (computer-generated)? And did the show just feature humans, or were there other creatures (or robots) involved?

Comment: I'm going to say 2005? Im pretty sure it was 2D animation, featuring humans

Comment: Would you mind to [edit] that in, @Jordan? Also, welcome to [fantasy.se]. Please take the [tour]. Also, please register your account, that makes participating a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

Could be Digimon Tamers. It originally ran 2001-2002.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digimon_Tamers

See if this rings any bells:

Its kids collecting cards by defeating monsters which give them powers of those monster. Once they slash the card, their digimon can use the same attack as what is written on card.

My other idea is that it could be "Redakai, Conquer the Kairu". Example fight.

In this case, kids themselves combine with their cards to use the card abilities. But that one ran from 2011 to 2015 or so.